# Detecting focus-out event on a frame

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a GtkFrame containing a set of GtkEntries. I want to hide this GtkFrame when the focus is removed from the GtkFrame.
I connected an handler to the "focus-out-event" signal of the frame, but it nevers get's invoked.

Any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that your frame just never had the focus !

Try to give it the focus first :

```
 theFrame.grab_focus()
```

Hope it works (I didn't test it)

---

"So what I need to "detect" is when the focus moves out of an element contained on the frame"

You may connect an event "focus-out-event" to every entry of your frame such as :

```
def outOfFocus(self, widget):
    focusInFrame = False
    for child in widget.get_parent():
        if child.has_focus():
            focusInFrame = True
    if focusInFrame == False:
        theFrame.hide()
```

I still did not test it, but will have more time this evening.

Comment: The issue that the focus is not expected to be at theFrame per si, the focus will be at some gtkEntry field contained on the frame. So what I need to "detect" is when the focus moves out of an element contained on the frame.

Comment: I completed my answer, check it out !

Comment: Did not work, it seems that the focus-out handler is invoked before the focus is actually set to the new element :(

Comment: Following your idea I have found a solution. I am connecting to the "set-focus" event of the top level window, on the handler I check if the set-focus target is out of the frame. Setting as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Looks pretty too -- thanks for sharing yours and accepting my solution !